# Создание автономного скрипта

Tags: python

Задача такая: нужно парсить новости, как только они выходят, с нескольких сайтов, а затем собирать их вместе в один json для дальнейшего использования.

У меня готовы парсеры для каждого сайта и скрипт, который асинхронно собирает новые новости раз в какое-то время с каждого парсера.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы этот скрипт работал постоянно в фоне, как например службы в Windows?

Comment: Просто запускаете через pythonw, он будет в фоне работать, без всяких служб.

Comment: @insolor Это похоже на решение, но дело в том, что мой скрипт срабатывает единожды. Как можно его зациклить? Будет ли использование while true здесь уместным?

Comment: Можно и while True, только паузу добавьте, чтобы все процессорное время не съедало.

Comment: @insolor Понял, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32gui, win32con

The_program_to_hide = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(The_program_to_hide , win32con.SW_HIDE)
```

Надеюсь, что это то что нужно